# Enable and disable TextView background color

Tags: android

I have four TextView and user can select only one at a time. I want to change the background color of the selected textView, and if user select any other textview the previous selected textView  should be disable.

Here is my Xml for the TextView:

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/goalText2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_border_rounded"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_margin="18dp"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/goal2"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="21sp"/>
```

I have created a separate xml for the textView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="50dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="50dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="50dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/white" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="@color/transparent_white" android:endColor="@color/transparent_white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I tried to do it programmatically but it didn't work for me.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.goalText1:
            if(mGoal1.isSelected())
                mGoal1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            break;
       }
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do it?

Comment: you are trying to implement RadioButton by youself. WhY?

Comment: @VladMatvienko sorry i didn't get you. Where I am applying Radio button?

Comment: The functionality you are trying to implement is a functionality of the RadioButton. Use RadioButton.

Comment: @VladMatvienko so how can we implement in textView

Comment: sorry, I can only help with a correct solution. Using TextView is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the state_selected attribute in your background xml:

```
<item android:state_selected="true">...</item>
```

Then in code you can:

```
mGoal2.setSelected(true); 
mGoal1.setSelected(false);
```

To change the background.